# SurveyEditor survey-react error

Tags: reactjs

I want to integrate survey-react (https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Builder/) in my project but I have a problem in the import of SurveyEditor.

```
var editor = new SurveyEditor.SurveyEditor("editorElement", editorOptions);
```

I get:

> 'SurveyEditor' is not defined  no-undef

Can someone help me please in this problem?

[image]

Comment: How are you resolving the dependencies? Can you post some more complete code including your `import` or `require` lines?